# Gnome printing (Evince): Scale pdf up and center (get rid of page margin)

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

As you know, latex documents often have quite a substantial amount of page margin. I don't like that.

The printing dialog offers the option to print the document scaled up (let's say 120%), but then the whole document is moved towards the bottom-right corner.

How to center such enlarged pdf? I'd prefer a solution that does not involve preprocessing of the pdf in any way, because it is just one more step (and I am already doing it with pdfjam - looking for a better way).

Comment: Hmmm....Are latex documents and pdf documents the same thing?

Comment: A latex document is preprocessed to pdf. You cannot modify it after that.

Comment: Hmmm....if you have the pdf, aren't there tools out there to possibly make the modifications you desire?

Comment: If you are creating the PDF from LaTeX yourself, then modify the LaTeX document, not the PDF (just stating the obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Calibre's [`ebook-viewer`](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/viewer.html) allows you to set margins when printing a PDF.
However it is extremely slow on some of the PDFs I have (IIRC the PDF files with scanned images that I have not yet converted to DjVu).

[image]